# How to solve route not defined in laravel 5.3?

Tags: php, laravel, get, routes, laravel-5.3

My controller code is like this :

```
public function store(CreateUserRequest $request)
{
    $input = $request->all();

    $user = $this->userRepository->create($input);

    Flash::success('User saved successfully.');

    return redirect(route('user.index.'.$input['year']));
}
```

There is exist error like this :

> InvalidArgumentException in UrlGenerator.php line 314: Route
>   [users.index.2016] not defined.

When error, the url look like this : `http://localhost/mysystem/public/users`

My routes\web.php is like this :

```
Route::get('users/index/{year}', 'UserController@index')->name('users.index.year');

Route::get('users/create/{year}', 'UserController@create')->name('users.create.year');

Route::resource('users', 'UserController');
```

I want the url look like this : `http://localhost/mysystem/public/users/index/2016`

Is there any people who can help me?

Comment: `user.index` only or `user.index.year` the place holder is not part of the name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call the [`route()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers#method-route) function as:

```
route('users.index.year', ['year' => $year])
```